# How to deal with the Google Chrome about crossing domain

Tags: javascript, webserver

[image]

I got a cross domain error on my local computer (although the code works perfectly on our web server). This is a real pain in the development of docking, so I want to know is this - can I adjust the settings in Chrome to get this error locally?

Comment: Did you try: chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests and  chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: It sounds like chrome wants the content from an HTTPS server ... but I don't know what you are attempting to access the ... allow insecure localhost ... should allow a HTTP request [which on server must be a HTTPS request] to operate on localhost. Might be another flag involved. so let me know if it worked.

Comment: If you are reading the information from a non-localhost system. You will likely need to make the request to your localhost and use a PHP wrapper to get the information from the remote host. But if it must be a HTTPS you will still need to use flags to get chrome into development modes to allow that from an HTTP://localhost

Comment: I have left the javascript tag on the question, though I think that the true answer is adding a CORS policy on the web server